The intersection of all non-empty open subsets of an irreducible scheme is the generic point
Let $X$ be an irreducible scheme, and let $\eta$ be its generic point. I want to show that the intersection of all non-empty open subsets of $X$ is $\{\eta\}$.
My solution: We know $\{\eta\}$ is dense, so it intersects every non-empty open subset non-trivially. Suppose we have another element in the intersection of all non-empty open subsets. Then it too must be dense, but our generic point is unique since $X$ is irreducible. Contradiction!
Issue: another proof I found online was more involved, and I cannot tell if I am missing something or if my proof is correct? Thanks for any help!

Seems ok to me, could you share the reference of the other proof ?

It's the solution to 6 in this PDF: https://metaphor.ethz.ch/x/2017/fs/401-3146-12L/ex/SolSheet6.pdf

The solution is pretty much your argument. It says that if $x$ is any other point of the scheme different from the generic point, then there is a nonempty open subset to which it does not belong.
